# Save multiple dataframes to the same file, one after the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have three dfs

```
x,y,z
0,1,1,1
1,2,2,2
2,3,3,3

a,b,c
0,4,4,4
1,5,5,5
2,6,6,6

d,e,f
0,7,7,7
1,8,8,8
2,9,9,9
```

How can I stick them all together so that i get:

```
x,y,z
0,1,1,1
1,2,2,2
2,3,3,3
a,b,c
0,4,4,4
1,5,5,5
2,6,6,6
d,e,f
0,7,7,7
1,8,8,8
2,9,9,9
```

I am not fussed if it's in a df or not hence I haven't included a new index. Essentially I just want to glue n amount of dfs together to save me having to copy and paste the data into an excel sheet myself.

Comment: An XY problem if I've ever seen one. Why not focus on how to automate getting your data into excel instead of asking for a workaround?

Comment: You understand that the column labels are not part of the actual data, right?

Comment: Tbh I dont use excel its literally just to check some values by hand if I did this a lot then I would look to automate and come up with a better solution but this is a one of problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save all your dataframes in the **same file** one after the other, use a simple loop with [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and use the file append mode (**a**):

```py
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

for d in dfs:
    d.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a')
```

*NB. the initial file must be empty or non existent*

output `out.csv`:

```
,x,y,z
0,1,1,1
1,2,2,2
2,3,3,3
,a,b,c
0,4,4,4
1,5,5,5
2,6,6,6
,d,e,f
0,7,7,7
1,8,8,8
2,9,9,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method of DataFrame.

```
print(df1.to_csv(index=False))
print(df2.to_csv(index=False))
print(df3.to_csv(index=False))
```

That being said, there is a [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method as well that may solve the potential [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/438222) referenced in the comments.

Comment: Hi thanks for this i know how to export dfs the issue is i just want one df with all my dfs in it rather than 3 seperate which i then have to copy and paste into one. Its literally a one off case to do some manual calculations and to save me 30 mins or so copying and pasting a lot of dfs

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```py
start_df = df1
other_dfs = [df2, df3]
new_df = pd.concat([start_df, *[x[::-1].append(dict(zip(x.columns, x.columns)), ignore_index=True)[::-1].reset_index(drop=True).set_axis(start_df.columns, axis=1) for x in other_dfs]], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
    x  y  z
0   1  1  1
1   2  2  2
2   3  3  3
3   a  b  c
4   4  4  4
5   5  5  5
6   6  6  6
7   d  e  f
8   7  7  7
9   8  8  8
10  9  9  9
```

Basically what we're doing here is, for each df in `other_dfs`, we reverse it, append the columns of that dataframe to the end, re-reverse it, change its columns to match `start_df`'s columns, and then we concatenate them all together.

Comment: Why are the reversals needed?

Comment: @Karl because `.append` appends to the end of the dataframe, but this time the data needs to be prepended. I'll see if there's a more elegant solution...